# vue bootstrap page size issue

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, nuxt.js

I have a simple `vue` app based on this official [example](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-external-jwt)
What I've added is this [template](https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/login/) for the login page. When displaying the login page directly by URL it is being rendered correctly:

[image: correct sizing]

But when I got it via the link from another page it is being sized incorrectly:

[image: incorrect sizing]

How could it be fixed? Thanks!

ps: sorry, I could not make an online example, just the entire source code on [github](https://github.com/khataev/bet-advizor-bot)

Comment: If you can't provide a link to an actual example you make it impossible for anyone to help. You're obviously loading CSS/SCSS in a way that it applies in one case and not the other. To suggest a solution we'd need to know how you do it now and you haven't shown any of that. Use [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) or a similar provider to provide an example.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu sorry, could not make online version of my project on codesandbox, could you check my sourcecode? Thanks https://github.com/khataev/bet-advizor-bot